# Подсчет количества строк с необходимым словом

Tags: c#

У меня сторонняя программа выдаёт текстовый документ. В нём всего два слова: OK и Failed. На одну строку одно слово. Подскажите, как можно подсчитать количество слов OK и Failed?

Comment: Сравнить каждую строку с образцом с помощью if?

Comment: Условно `var okCount = File.ReadAllLines("...").Count(x=>x.Contains("OK"));`, более точно если, то нужен уже самодостаточный пример, по которому можно работать, ибо сейчас все абстрактно, может там каждая строка имеет свой вид, а может этот файл вообще имеет csv/json/xml формат, мы ведь этого не знаем.

Comment: Подсчёт идёт из текстового документа формата *.txt только два слова в верхнем регистре

Comment: Ну, тогда вариант выше я дал, пробуйте. Но учтите, если встречаются слова, которые содержат "ОК", допустим не знаю, OKEY, то мой вариант это тоже посчитает, если такое не подходит, то разбивайте по словам, или ищите то, что уникальное для вашего "ОК", например строка начинается с ОК, тогда `.StartWith()` лучше использовать в этом случае.

Comment: Вместо `ReadAllLines` лучше использовать `ReadLines`, чтобы читать построчно, а не весь текст разом. Вдруг он очень большим окажется.

Answer (score -1):

```
int count = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(path_base).Length;
```

Comment: Подсчет количества строк **с необходимым словом**.